# How can I make my 2 images fade-in when I'm scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to get a fade-in effect on my images when I'm scrolling.

I've tried some methods but it's not working.
In my codepen, the images and text have disappeared.

Does anyone have any idea how can I achieve that? I'm still learning it.

Here's my codepen if you wanna check : https://codepen.io/Softee/pen/vYVGYbp
Thanks in advance for your help

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', reveal);

function reveal(){
    var reveals = document.querySelectorAll('reveal');

    for(var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++){

        var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
        var revealtop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var revealpoint = 150;

        if(revealtop < windowheight - revealpoint){
            reveals[i].classList.add('active');
        }
        else{
            reveals[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#histoire{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
}

#histoire header{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#histoire h1{
    border-bottom:5px solid #1B1B1B;
    width: 40%;
    font-family: englishtowne, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #1B1B1B;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

.histoire_texte{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.histoire_texte div {
    margin: auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.histoire_texte img{
    width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.histoire_texte p{
    font-size: 1.5rem
    }

.reveal{
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(150px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

.reveal.active{
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <section id="histoire">
        <header>
            <h1>Histoire</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="histoire_texte reveal">
            <div><span><img src="https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/13/Pngitem-PNG-Clipart-Background.png"></span></div>

      <div><span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur nulla aperiam veniam tempora labore minus nam saepe vero cum itaque alias, dolor, odio iste tempore placeat quas nihil sit fuga? 

      <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur nulla aperiam veniam tempora labore minus nam saepe vero cum itaque alias, dolor, odio iste tempore placeat quas nihil sit fuga?

      <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, assumenda?</p></span></div>
      
            <div><span><img src="https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/13/Pngitem-PNG-Clipart-Background.png"></span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Problem aside, You can use [AOS library](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in your queryselectorall this:

```
var reveals = document.querySelectorAll('reveal');
```

should be:

```
var reveals = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');
```